# my own constraints Google or-tools

Tags: python, constraint-programming, or-tools

I'm new in CP problems and OR-Tools in Python and I want to do the follows:

```
# declare variables
for i in range(I):
    for k in range(K):
        x[i,k]=solver.IntVar(0,N,"x %i %i " % (i,k))

#constraints
solver.Add(CustomFunction[(x[i,k])] == 1) # only consider the values of x[i,k] evaluated in CustomFunction is equal to 1
```

BUT I get the error at the moment of evaluate the `CustomFunction`:

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),
>   numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

This is right because `x` is a IntVar.

By the otherhand, I saw in https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/constraint_solver/constraint_solver/Solver/  that I could add a custom constraint, but I do not know how to do it in Python.

I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, adding new constraint is not implemented in the original CP solver.
And this solver is deprecated in favor of the CP-SAT solver.
The new solver does not support adding new constraints, but has a much more expressive modeling language thanks to the support of boolean constraints and enforcement literals.

See:

- https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver#cp-solver_example/
- https://github.com/google/or-tools/tree/stable/ortools/sat/doc

Anyway, this does not solve the basis of your questions. You cannot embed any arbitrary code inside a CP solver (original or CP-SAT).

One way is to pre-compute all possible assignments, and add that in a AllowedAssignment constraint.